# RadGrid Bind Image from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nullreferenceexception, radgrid

I am using the following code to bind image from the database to my asp:Image control in the RadGrid Mastertable. However I am getting a null reference exceptionon the line "   iP.ImageUrl = "~/StreamImage.ashx?Id=" + user;" and I am not able to understand why is it giving me that
Here is the code:

```
 <asp:Image ID="iPhoto1" runat="server" AlternateText="Profile Picture"    
 />


 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

 var data = ss.qStudSearch(Common.GetValue(txtName.Text), 
        Common.GetValue(txtResearch.Text), currUser.iProgramID);

        rgSearch.DataSource = data;

        rgSearch.DataBind();


        foreach (GridDataItem d in rgSearch.MasterTableView.Items)
        {

                int user = Convert.ToInt32(d.GetDataKeyValue("upid"));
                var pix = ss.GetPics(user);


                Image iP = 
                (Image)rgSearch.MasterTableView.FindControl("iPhoto1");

            if (pix != null)
            {

                iP.ImageUrl = "~/StreamImage.ashx?Id=" + user;
            }
            else
            {
                iP.ImageUrl = "~/images/no_image.jpg";
            }


           }


       }
```

The getpics method retrieves the images from the database and it is retrieving it properly as I checked it by debugging. However I am not able to assign it to the asp:Image control.. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that either `iP` is null, or `user` is null. Put a breakpoint before the assignment of iP.ImageUrl and inspect the items to see which one is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind directly using binary image column but it's got slow performance with the data:

```
<telerik:GridBinaryImageColumn DataField="image" HeaderText="Photo" AllowFiltering="false" 
     UniqueName="LogoView" ImageAlign="NotSet" ImageHeight="80px" ImageWidth="80px" 
     ResizeMode="Fit" DataAlternateTextField="image">
   <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
</telerik:GridBinaryImageColumn>
```